# xlwings - Get data range of existing chart

Tags: python, excel, graph, xlwings

let's say I have an excel file, where there is data from A1 to C5. Meaning it looks like this:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1997 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1997 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1997 | 3 | 5 |

I now have one graph that plots the first time series B so the range of the graph is "A1:B3". The second graph is plotting time series C so the range in xlwings language is ("A1:A3, C1:C3").

What I want to do is open the graph in python with xlwings and extract the range of the graph. I already tried:

```
wb = xw.Book("myfile.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheets["mysheet"]
for chart in ws.charts:
    
    print(chart.parent.used_range)
```

But this only gives back the range of all data of that sheet. So in this case "A1:C3" and not the range of the data the chart uses.

Is there any way to extract the exact range of data the chart uses?

Best,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Even directly in VBA, the overall chart source data range is not available. In many cases, this range is undefined: if series have different X values, for example, or if series have a different number of points, or if series are plotted out of order, etc.

But you can get the range for the individual series in the chart through the series formulas, and along with some validation and adjustment, merge these ranges to get the source data range.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do you know how to extract the series formula in xlwings? I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Never used xlwings. How closely does it follow Excel VBA's Object Model? I just took a quick look, and the API seems woefully inadequate for the simple task you need.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I now solved it with named ranges that adapt to the length of the data. Its now more cumbersome to add new charts, but I could not find a solution. For anybody running into the same problem, you only need to be careful when pushing data with xlwings to the file, do not change the value in the most upper left corner of your named range as this will delete your range.

Comment: I had a look at xlwings after commenting, and it appears that it only includes a tiny subset of the object model that's available in Excel VBA. Too bad.